# UPDATE query through foreach loop in mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql

I do have an array something like this:

```
[cuisines] => Array
    (
        [0] => 17
        [1] => 20
        [2] => 23
        [3] => 26
    )
```

Now I need to update mysql table with these values. All values belong to one user.

So I tried it like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['cuisines'])) {    
    $cuisines = $_POST['cuisines'];         
} else {
    $error_alert[] = "Please select at least one cuisine";
}   

if (empty($error_alert)) { // If everything's OK... 

    // Make the update query:
    $sql = 'UPDATE restaurant_cuisines 
                        SET restaurant_id = ?
                            , cuisine_id = ?  
                    WHERE restaurant_id = ?'; 

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    // Bind the variables:
    $stmt->bind_param('iii', $restaurant_id, $cuisine_id, $restaurant_id);

    foreach ($cuisines as $value) {
        $cuisine_id = $value;
        // Execute the query:
        $stmt->execute();       
    }   

    // Print a message based upon the result:
    if ($stmt->affected_rows >= 1) {
        echo 'updated';

    } 
    // Close the statement:
    $stmt->close();
    unset($stmt);
}
```

But this query not updating mysql correctly. This is what I get running this script.

```
mysql> select * from restaurant_cuisines where restaurant_id = 4;
+---------------+------------+
| restaurant_id | cuisine_id |
+---------------+------------+
|             4 |         26 |
|             4 |         26 |
|             4 |         26 |
+---------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What would be the problem of this script? 
Hope somebody may help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: `...SET restaurant_id = ?, ... WHERE restaurant_id = ?';`? Why are you trying to update a value with the value that you have in your `WHERE` clause. If the value is the same it will never change. If the value was changed, it will not be in the table, so it will never change.

Comment: Oh I got... I dont need to update restaurant_id. isn't it?

Comment: What is your desired result? It looks like it is working to me. You are updating the same `restaurant_id` in your loop, so it will end with the last array value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind your parameters in the loop:

```
// Delete old entries:
$sqlDelete = 'DELETE FROM restaurant_cuisines WHERE restaurant_id = ?'; 
$stmtDelete = $mysqli->prepare($sqlDelete);
$stmtDelete->bind_param($restaurant_id);
$stmtDelete->execute(); 
$stmtDelete->close();
unset($stmtDelete);  

// now prepare to insert new values
$sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO restaurant_cuisines (restaurant_id,cuisine_id) 
              VALUES (?,?)'; 
$stmtInsert = $mysqli->prepare($sqlInsert);

foreach ($cuisines as $value) {

    // Bind the variables:
    $stmtInsert->bind_param($restaurant_id, $value);

    // Execute the query:
    $stmtInsert->execute();    

    // Print a message based upon the result:
    if ($stmtInsert->affected_rows >= 1) {
        echo 'updated';
    }   
}   
// Close the statement:
$stmtInsert->close();
unset($stmtInsert);
```

Comment: You only need to prepare the query once. Then bind and/or execute with different parameters upon each iteration. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484630/when-making-the-same-pdo-query-with-changing-parameters-do-i-call-prepare-e).

Comment: this is wrong. the purpose of `->prepare()`/->bind_param()` is that it is only called once, outside a loop, and then you only need to change the param value(s) in the loop to excecute.

Comment: I tried it like this. But it doesn't work for me.. problem is still same

Comment: Where do you have `$restaurant_id` defined? Also it's not needed in the `SET ... `

Comment: it comed session. in this case it is `4`

Comment: Only updating 3 rows with last value of `cuisines` array.

Comment: My updated foreach - `foreach ($cuisines as $value) {
 $stmt->bind_param('ii', $value, $restaurant_id);
 $stmt->execute();
}`

Comment: @AlexTartan. I too think like that.. Probably it will be the solution. Before doing it, I looked for a solution with `update`. Thats why I ask this question.

Comment: Updated with "delete and insert"

Comment: @AlexTartan look again at the OP's logic. ie. http://stackoverflow.com/users/3733831/user3733831 && http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544603/update-query-through-foreach-loop-in-mysql-php?noredirect=1#comment51049837_31545319 They are updating in a loop with the same `$restaurant_id` for every query, so the rows will always end up with the last array value.

Comment: @Sean You're right and I was missing the point. I think that's why Alex chose a "delete and re-insert" method.